# Problem Using SSH Key to Authenticate to GitLab.com

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I just joined gitlab, was formally on using GitHub, still is.
I created a new project on gitlab and I am trying to push but am getting a permission denied(public key) error.

This are the list of files I have in the ssh folder on my system:

1. github_rsa,
2. github_rsa.pub,
3. known_hosts.

When I checked for how to generate an ssh key, I saw on gitlab that firstly I should type `%userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` in command line to check if I have it and I typed it in exactly as `%userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`, and I got this

```
C:\Users\slodd' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.
```

I don't know if I typed it in wrong by typing it in exactly because I actually just copied and pasted it on commandline.
I haven't worked with ssh keys before. I'm using a windows 10 system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to generate an ssh key dedicated to your gitlab server:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f "%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\gitlab_rsa" -C "key for GitLab access" -q -P ""
```

Make sure your `<git>/usr/bin` folder is in your `%PATH%` for `ssh-keygen` to be recognized as a command.

Then [reference your private key in your `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/config` file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#tip-non-default-openssh-key-file-names-or-locations).

```
#
# Main gitlab.com server
#
Host gitlab.com
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile 'C:\Users\slodd\.ssh\gitlab_rsa
User git
```